# nested_attributes and saved_changes does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a problem with saved_changes ActiveRecord method returning blank values when the change was triggered by a child updated from nested attributes.

Given these two models:

```ruby
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {inactive: 0, active: 1, paused: 2}, _prefix: :status

  has_many :customer_pauses
  has_many :contracts

  after_save :handle_status_change

  protected

  # UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR HAPPENS HERE!!!
  def handle_status_change
    puts "CHANGED STATUS??? #{saved_change_to_status?}"
    puts saved_changes
    puts "--------------------"
    if saved_change_to_status?
      contracts.where(status: saved_change_to_status.first).update status: status
    end
  end

end
```

```ruby
class CustomerPause < ApplicationRecord

  enum status: {disabled: 0, scheduled: 1, ongoing: 2, finished: 3}, _prefix: :status

  belongs_to :customer
  after_save :update_customer_status

  protected

  #update customer status to match the status of the pause accordingly
  def update_customer_status
    if (saved_change_to_status? || new_record?)
      if status_ongoing? && customer.status_active?
        customer.update status: Customer::STATUS_PAUSED
      end
    end
  end

end
```

These differences in behavior happen:

```ruby
customer = Customer.create status: :active
pause = customer.customer_pauses.create status: :disabled
pause.status = :ongoing

#this works as expected, and customer.saved_changes will contain the status change
pause.save

#This however will result in saved_changes to be empty on the customer callback "handle_status_change"
#Note that the customer status is still changed but not listed in saved_changes
customer.update customer_pauses_attributes: [pause.attributes]
```

I'm not sure why this happens, is this the expected behavior or a bug in rails?

Should a callback on a nested child not cause changes to its parent?